# orde links by their hosts - from a multi link textarea to a table ordred by host (colomn n = host n contains all links of that host)

Tags: php

```
$multi = $_Post['multi_links'];
$links = explode("\n", $multi);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($links); $i++) 
{ 
$link=$links[$i]; 
$host = array_shift( explode( '.', str_replace('www.', '', parse_url($link,   PHP_URL_HOST))));
 ... 
}
```

what should i write in (...) to reorganise the links if they contain the same host and thanks ... here an exemple :
    if $multi="a.com/abc
    b.com/toto
    a.com/def
    b.com/cc
    b.com/ccc"
i get in every link the following :
    link for host 'a.com' = 'a.com/abc | a.com/def'
    link for host 'b.com' = 'b.com/toto | b.com/cc | b.com/ccc'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$multi = "http://a.com/abc
    http://b.com/toto
    http://a.com/def
    http://b.com/cc
    http://b.com/ccc";
$links = explode("\n", $multi);
//remove white spaces (trimming)
$links = array_filter(array_map('trim', $links));
//unique hosts
$hosts = array();
foreach($links as $link){
    $parsed_url = parse_url($link);
    $hosts[] = $parsed_url['host'];
}
//filter only the unique host names
$unique_host = array_unique($hosts);

//group links
$group = array();
foreach($unique_host as $u_h){
    $group[$u_h]=array();
    foreach($links as $link){
        $parsed_url=parse_url($link);
        if(strcasecmp($parsed_url['host'],$u_h) == 0){
            $group[$u_h][] = $link;
        }
    }
}
print_r($group);
```

Comment: but i have a question : the links i want to get are like this h t t p : //host.com/testetst ... i want to get the host like this and can you please tell me how i can put all the range of links with same host in one variable !

Answer (score 0):

According to what you've described , you just need a function that will sort
the links by the abc.

```
function just_host($link)
{
return array_shift( explode( '.', str_replace('www.', '', parse_url($link,   PHP_URL_HOST))));
}

$multi = $_POST['multi_links']; //$_Post is not right , all upper-case!
$links = explode("\n", $multi);
$links = array_map($links , 'just_host'); //Call the 'just_host' for every link and update the value in the array.
sort($links); //Sort the array
foreach($links as $link) //Instead of 'for' , use 'foreach'
{ 
echo $link . "<br />";
}
```

Should work , please update me if not and I'll edit it.

Comment: 3 Errors saying that parmeter 1 in sort() and array-map should be array

Comment: Make sure that `$links` is an array... I thought it was obvious

Answer (score 0):

```
$multi = $_Post['multi_links'];
$links = explode("\n", $multi);
$hname = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($links); $i++) 
{ 
$link=$links[$i]; 
$host = array_shift( explode( '.', str_replace('www.', '', parse_url($link,   PHP_URL_HOST))));

$exh = explode('/', $host);
if (array_key_exists($exh[0], $hname))
{
   array_push($hname[$exh[0]], exh[1]);  
}
else
{
  $hname[$exh[0]] = array();
}

}
```

Where `$hname` is the associative array which keys are domains and values are arrays of rests of links.